# How to solve Checkmarx vulnerability - 'Client Insufficient ClickJacking Protection' in Angular code, reported on some component HTML pages?

Tags: angular, checkmarx

Checkmarx scan reports "Client Insufficient ClickJacking Protection" vulnerability on Angular component HTML pages.

Here is one page:
File Name src/app/app.component.html

```
<div class="home-page-container">
```

Here is another one:
File Name src/app/create.component.html

```
<div class="control-bar">
```

Checkmarx suggestions:
***The application does not protect the web page src/app/app.component.html from clickjacking attacks in legacy browsers, by using framebusting scripts.***

I have already implemented Frame busting code for legacy browsers in **index.html** page, as Angular code is a single page application.
And **X-Frame-Options** response header being set to **SAMEORIGIN** at hosting server.

But Checkmarx still reports this vulnerability in Component specific HTML pages.
How to remediate this vulnerability?

Here is framebusting code, added to **index.html** of Angular code -

```
<style> html {display : none; } </style>
<script>
    if ( self === top ) {
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
    top.location = encodeURI(self.location);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you please also share your framebusting code?

Comment: Updated question to add framebusting code. Please check.

Comment: the code appears to adhere with the checkmarx code remediation. can you confirm if the index.html file is included in the scan (and not excluded by accident)?

Comment: Yes, index.html is included in scan. Why would Checkmarx point out app.component.html and create.component.html? 
These component views in Angular gets compiled into javascript anyways. 
Is Checkmarx missing any configuration to understand Angular phenomena?

Comment: It probably depends on the version of Checkmarx you have. If I'm not mistaken, I think not all versions natively support Angular and may require some pre-processing before the scan similar to React. See this support article: https://support.checkmarx.com/s/article/How-to-Scan-React-JS-code-in-CxSAST